# How to get label's text

Tags: ios4

I am learning iPhone programming. I want to know how to get any value that label holds. In my case label text holds the float value (I am displaying that value from Slider's changed value). And I am trying to get that float value into a float variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps use the "floatValue" method of NSString

```
myFloat = [myLable.text floatValue];
```